# Update core data (magical record) with new location data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I have a function that is called every time the location update delegate is called. I'm sure this is not the best way to go about this, since updating this often can be expensive. Could someone point me into the right direction of making the update every 10 seconds or so?

My current code:

```
TrackCoords *oTR= [TrackCoords MR_createEntity];
oTR.speed=[NSNumber numberWithInt:Location.speed*2.2369362920544];
oTR.lat=[NSNumber numberWithInt:Location.coordinate.latitude];
oTR.lon=[NSNumber numberWithInt:Location.coordinate.longitude];
oTR.elevation=[NSNumber numberWithInt:Location.altitude];

[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

Comment: Be clear about what you need to save. Is this running all the time? The 10 second period is just for Core Data?

Comment: this would be running for the entire time a track or path is being recorded. I mostly need the coords and a few other bit of info to recreate the track

Answer (score 1):

You code looks fine. It is not too frequent as far as Core Data is concerned.

If you are concerned about "expensive", also in the sense of battery drain etc., try reducing the updates sent to the location manager delegate, by observing only significant location change.

Comment: thanks, I was more worried about loss of any data.  I assume that core data handles the queuing in the background.

Comment: CoreData does not do things in the background unless you tell it to. The code you have here does look like it's run on the main thread (or at least in the thread of the delegate callback method). I suggest that you use the [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:] API to do stuff in the background. Then, your queuing handled by GCD.

Comment: That is certainly an option. But this short save should hardly be noticeable on the main thread.